# Git Push after Pull and Add - other users files affected

Tags: git, github, pull

I recently followed the tried and true method of:

```
Git pull
Git add (my files)
Git commit 
Git push
```

To update the remote repository with my changes. The repo is up to date but it shows that I committed other users files and responsible for those changes. I synced with other users and they say files are up to date.

How was I able to push other people’s changes in my commit?

My repo doesn’t allow me to git fetch then push without pulling first. Did I pull committed but un-pushed changes in my git pull and then push those changes along with my commit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are getting some terminology wrong, and will need to clarify: 1.) When you did the command `git commit`, look at the commit you created to see if you included other files that weren't yours in there. (If you did that might answer your question.) 2.) You said, "My repo doesn’t allow me to git fetch then push so it requires explicit git pull". That doesn't really make sense. You may not have permission to push certain branches directly without a Pull Request, but you will be able to both fetch and pull. 3.) You can't pull "un-pushed" changes. Stuff you pulled was already pushed...

Comment: I'd start by looking at the commit(s) you created and make sure they only have the changes in them that you expect.

Comment: Note that `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command to do something with the fetched commits*. This was literally true—in that `git pull` ran the other two commands as separate commands—until recently when `git pull` was rewritten as a single program that incorporates the other two programs. The other Git your Git talks do, when it does the fetch step, still can't tell whether you're running an older Git binary and hence actually using `git fetch`, or a newer one and hence using the combined program. If you can pull, you can fetch.

Comment: You are right that I don’t have permissions to push to this branch without pulling first. However, when I ran commit, I only included my files individually in the git add(I.e. git add file 1, git add file 2 then git commit). @TTT It is probably true that I included other user files in my commit, but how if I didn’t explicitly add them and ran a pull first? As you say, a pull shouldn’t pull unpushed commits. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @coder_bob you say "probably true that I included other user files in my commit"... let's confirm that. You can view the changes in any commit to see exactly what was changed. Please first confirm if your commit actually has extra changes you didn't intend to commit. If it doesn't, then the changes are coming from a different commit, perhaps because your branch is bringing in more commits than you intended.

Comment: Yes, check/show the changes of your commits. `git log -p`, `git log --name-status`, `gitk`, … should all help

Comment: Yes. I was able to confirm that my commit included changes to two files that I did not edit or git add.

Comment: @coder_bob is "your" commit a merge commit? Did pulling result in merge conflicts and had you resolve the conflicts? In that case, you are not creating a new commit with `git commit`, but are confirming the conflict resolution by making the merge commit.

Comment: @knittl yes it is a merge commit.  My git repo requires a pull before pushing commit. Looking at history, my merge commit reflects recently committed changes from other user my pull brought down. Is there a way to commit without “re committing” these already committed files from the pull?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "my repo requires a pull before pushing", as mentioned above by user TTT.  You can never push if your branches have diverged, but that is just how Git works. You then need to consolidate the history either by merging or rebasing your local changes. If there are conflicts, you must resolve (and commit) them. What do you expect to happen if you don't commit the conflict resolution – how would Git know what the file contents should be?

Comment: @coder_bob and as it stands, this question is lacking detail or focus. I think the list of commands is not complete. Without seeing the history or changes of the commits, it is almost impossible to give a helpful answer.